# Multiplatform Premake Script

Tags: premake

I'm the author of Node9, a hosted, hybrid OS that combines Inferno and LuaJIT to create an interactive, distributed development environment. See the project here: https://github.com/jvburnes/node9

I created a basic 4.x premake script to compile all of the dependencies and main source code for OSX, but now people are asking for build configurations for Linux, BSD and Windows.   I have the code to do this and I want to create premake configurations to build and run Node9 on these OSs. I'll need to set library and include search paths, compiler names, as well as per-platform defines.

1. Can anyone point me to a good multi platform premake script?
2. Do I use "premake gmake" and sense the native platform somehow or do I need to explicitly place the target platform on the command line and refer to that platform in the premake Configuration and Platform sections?
3. I heard that premake 4.x was legacy and that premake 5.x is the solution going forward.  Is it stable and available enough to build for all these platforms?

I know that's a lot of questions, but I want to do this right.

Thanks.

Comment: I'll eventually want to cross-compile to Android NDK.  I know there's a 3rd party module for that, but I don't if it runs on 4.x or 5.x.

Comment: All modules are for 5.0.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in multiplatform compilation, but here are some things that might help you. First, I strongly advise you to switch to Premake5. It's stable, the community works on it and is quite active, and you have support for modules (Android ? :p) and a lot of cool other features.

As for your questions:

1. I can't, but basically it should be as simple as something like this:

   ```
   solution "multiplatform_solution"
       configurations { "debug", "release", "whatever" }

       -- now here, you define your supported platforms
       platforms {
           "win32",
           "win64",
           "macos",
           "linux86",
           "linux64",
           -- etc.
       }

       project "some_project"

           -- now you can configure some things per platform:
           filter { "platforms:win32" }
               -- some defines, some specific paths to libs, etc.
               -- specific to win 32
               defines { "WIN32" }
           filter { "platforms:macos" }
               -- macos specific configurations
               defines { "you_fool_" } -- yes, it's a troll :p
           -- etc.

           -- and configure the rest as usual
   ```
2. When you invoke `premake gmake` you just tell premake to build a makefile for gmake. If you have gmake on Windows, MacOS and Linux, you can use `premake gmake` for all platforms. It's when you actually build that you just need to specify your configuration and platform. I don't know gmake well enough, but that might look something like this: `gmake config=release platform=linux32`
3. As I said, you probably want to update to Premake 5. I think it's stable enough, and in case of problem you can ask questions here :)

Comment: Thanks, Citron.  I thought the "platform" keyword seemed to be the solution for multi platform, but I wasn't sure whether it was intended for cross-compile or native compiles also.  Thanks for the details on "filter".  That's exactly what I need to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone point me to a good multi platform premake script?

If you look at a Premake source package, you'll see that it contains multiple makefiles, one for each platform it targets, in directories named like `build/gmake.windows` and `build/gmake.macosx`. That's one option.

Another approach is to put it all in one Makefile, like @Citron suggested in his script, and select the desired configuration on the command line at the time you do the build. In that case, your build command should look like:

```
$ make config=debug_win32
```

If you run the `help` target on the Premake generated Makefile it will give you a list of all the valid configuration options:

```
$ make help
```

Or, if you don't mind requiring your developers to have Premake installed locally, they can generate a makefile customized for their environment before building. In that case your script might look something like:

```
solution "MySolution"
   configuration { "Debug", "Release" }

   filter { "system:Windows" }
      -- windows specific stuff

   filter { "system:MacOSX" }
      -- mac specific stuff

   filter { "system:Linux" }
      -- etc.
```

In this case, running `premake5 gmake` will create a makefile targeted to the current environment.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty close.   I think a slightly closer answer would be to use filter on the "system:".  I think it's the difference between using premake to generate a multiplatform make and using it to build the current platform makefile.

It's the closest answer so far so I'll upvote it.

Comment: You should post replies like this as a comment on the answer, rather than as a new answer. It helps with the voting and keeps the discussion together for future visitors.